# How to open SlidingUpPanel from Right,Left and Bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am using SlidingUpPanel Library https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel but it open the panel only from bottom and top,i want to use it from left and right side too. 
i want the user to select on runtime that panel will open from which side? 
any one help me please? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That library doesn't support it.  There's a reason why its called "UpPanel".  Look for another solution, like DrawerLayout, which is in the support library.

Comment: Also Tried DrawerLayout, its Slide panel does not cover the whole screen,i want to open layout to cover full screen and it does not support bottom sliding.

Comment: Then you'll need to write your own. There's nothing built in that does it.

Comment: i am new in programming can you please guide me a from where i should start ?